# Defining models and dependencies in CAKEPHP

Tags: cakephp-4.x

I was using cakephp 1.x for sometime and discontinued its usage for a long time.  Now I am reverting to cakephp, but the version is 4.x and PHP and Mysql also have changed, and the old codes do not work.  I need to know where the models and hasone / hasmany dependencies are to be defined and stored.

Should it be in the 'src/model/table' sub-folder of the APPLICATION or do we need to create the folder on our own ? Can someone provide a sample of model with hasmany / hasone.

Comment: You should start with the docs, I would suggest to read them from start to finish, but for models specifically, start with **https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/orm.html**

Comment: Instead of writing any of that basic code on your own, very much recommend using the [`bake`](https://book.cakephp.org/bake/2/en/index.html) tool to generate it based on your database setup.

Comment: I tried the bake tool.  However, my previous experience was not based on bake tool, but was the outcome of the code snippets accumulated through net. At present, very little documentation is available on the net.  To my dismay, even the examples shown in the official documentation of CAKEPHP.ORG do not seem to be working.  (For example , the find() .  Hence I would appreciate whatever help could be had to get me going.  Thanks for responding.

Comment: As advised by Mr ndm, I accessed the official documentation and modified an example.                                                                                                                            But while running I am getting the error Call to a member function find() on null.public function junk()    {

// In a controller or table method.

$query = $units->find('all')->contain(['Atms']);

foreach ($query as $unit) {

    echo $unit->brName;



}